# Redirect /openvas/ to OpenVAS Scanner with NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, openvas

I'm trying to make my OpenVAS Scanner available via path in nginx.
So I tried

```
location /openvas/ {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;}
```

thats not working, it gives a blank page

When I change it to root

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; }
```

its working

when checking nginx logfiles it seems it gets the first page, but not the other files requested

```
"GET /openvas/ HTTP/2.0" 200
"GET /config.js HTTP/2.0" 404
```

Comment: How did you set up OpenVAS? Are you using the docker setup?

Comment: Please share some more information about the OpenVAS Backend. That will help answering the question.

Comment: Yes, OpenVAS is running in a container

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the docker container image and just proxying the traffic trough NGINX will not work. You have to set the Public Hostname for your OpenVAS instance as well to tell OpenVAS how to server static files and build directories in the frontend.

I have found this on docker hub.

```
docker run -d -p 443:443 -e PUBLIC_HOSTNAME=myopenvas.example.org --name openvas mikesplain/openvas
```

In your case you should set the `PUBLIC_HOSTNAME` to `example.com/openvas/`. This will tell OpenVAS public domain used to access the application.

Your NGINX configuration will be

```
location /openvas/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```